# Preparing a suspension by using non-chord tones in the bassline

Tags: nonchord-tones

Is there some kind of technical name for a suspension that is prepared by the bassline before the next harmony starts? So let's say that the note in question is not part of either of the two harmonies and even though the note resolves downward over the new harmony as a suspension does, it was not prepared in the previous harmony becuase it was a non chord to begin with. You could prepare the note by changing the bassline quickly at the end of the bar so that by the time the next bar starts the suspension has been prepared. is this even a thing? I see this a lot in my music books but have not read anything about it so would like to know more about it.

Comment: I'm getting a little lost visualizing the scenario; could you give a notated example? (heh, not that I'd have an answer; just curious)

Comment: That sounds like what I'd call a passing tone.

Comment: As generally understood in music theory, a suspension needs a consonant preparation. If "it was not prepared in the previous harmony because it was a non-chord [tone]," then it's not a suspension.  Simple.  If you "prepare the note by changing the bassline quickly at the end of the bar," presumably so that it's now consonant with the harmony, then it can be a proper suspension, as it now has consonant preparation.  "I see this a lot in my music books" -- could you give an example, as this sounds like a fairly unusual figure to me based on your description.

Comment: thank you for understanding my question. And changing this bass note  so that the melody is consonant with it, does this have some kind of name?

Comment: because you are essentially using a passing bass tone to prepare a suspension so there must be a term for this somewhere

Comment: Nope, I don't get it either. What are you doing, D in the bass against a C Maj, with the next chord A Maj? That's non-chord to suspension in the bass… but …

Comment: @Tetsujin read Athanisias comment, he gets it and perhaps explains better than I

Comment: @armani: It really would be helpful to see an example of what you're discussing. You say I understand it, but you also say you "see this a lot in my music books," but what I understand you to be describing doesn't sound like a common procedure (certainly not something with a specific name). Which leads me to think I'm overlooking or misunderstanding something. If you could give an example or two here, that might clear things up. Also, a "passing bass tone" to me implies a *dissonant* passing tone, which can't prepare a suspension as it would be dissonant with the overall harmony. I'm confused.

Comment: I can't figure out why you try to describe so specifically in words, but don't post notation. Even in text you could write `| chord | chord |` goes with bass `| note note | note note |`.